# Getting rid of inline JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been making a site with some image comparisons and I've temporarily "fixed" the problem with some inline JS. However, the amount of comparisons grew and since inline JS is not really good or professional, I'm asking what would be the best way to turn this excerpt below into a separate JS file:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;" onmouseover="document.Comp01.src='images/img2.jpg';" onmouseout="document.Comp01.src='images/img1.jpg';">
<img src="images/img1.jpg" name="Comp01"/></a>

<a href="" onclick="return false;" onmouseover="document.Comp02.src='images/img4.jpg';" onmouseout="document.Comp02.src='images/img3.jpg';">
<img src="images/img3.jpg" name="Comp02"/></a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `a` tags altogether, and add the rollover image into a `data-img2` attribute in each image tag. After those changes this javascript should do the trick:

```js
function switchImage() {
  var tmp = this.getAttribute('data-img2');
  this.setAttribute('data-img2', this.src);
  this.src = tmp;
}

var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {  
  imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', switchImage, false);
  imgs[i].addEventListener('mouseout', switchImage, false);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lvt3icqzzk1r2h6ioo1_500.jpg" data-img2="http://65.media.tumblr.com/6e84c41199dd134d22f5ce0f1dcbaadc/tumblr_nbm3wsXhRV1r2h6ioo1_500.jpg" />
<img src="http://66.media.tumblr.com/dc23e90fc500f0e48fa0108be589008b/tumblr_nbdb2mta9K1r2h6ioo1_500.jpg" data-img2="http://67.media.tumblr.com/ba9ceeab05ddf1e9825f97f37629965d/tumblr_mtg3fpQd6N1r2h6ioo1_500.jpg" />
```

Just make sure to run it in `body.onload` or at the bottom of your html.

Comment: +1 from me for mention body.onload and for kitties :). Add an example how to use it (onload, not kitties). Another point which I like is swapping src and data instead of closure. Less working part is your query selector.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot. One question though: Why should I use the onload event to call the function instead of referencing the external script? Is there any particular advantage? Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @jedi_coder Sorry, I was a bit unclear in my explanation. The point was that regardless of the way you include the script, it should be executed after the DOM has been loaded, i.e. the img tags exist, even though the images haven't necessarily been loaded yet. Otherwise the script wouldn't find all the tags it should. This might happen for example if you included the script in an external file from the head section of your html file, and didn't use the onload handler.

Comment: Oh, that's how I always do. JS always at the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you get a +1 from me, because you asking how to get better.

The answer from me is evolutionary.

1. You don't need anchor (a-tag). Try to place onmouseover/out on img-tag.
2. You can get elements with [getElementByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) or similar and attach an event listener to do same thing.
3. The next step could be to define a more generic logic. Like:

```js
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-mouseover]");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            var el = matches[i];
            var srcimg = el.src;
            el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
                el.src = srcimg;
            });
            el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                el.src = el.dataset.mouseover;
            });
        }
```

```html
<img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" data-mouseover="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/12/58/tv-test-pattern-146649_960_720.png" />
```

4. The next thing could be to use a framework. I like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). The way with Angular is to make a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for it. Angular is a little bit complicated for beginners, but from my point of view it's how web should work. Alternatively, you can try jQuery or prototype.js to make a browser compatibility higher and less code.

P.S. wow,my first snippet :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was trying to avoid using a framework if I could do it with a simple JS script, but I appreciate the help and your setp-by-step suggestion is a good alternative.

P.S: Will give you +1 once I get enough points.

Comment: In long term, you produce much more less maintainable code without framework. Frameworks often fix different browser quirks. Believe me, you don't want to fix it yourself.